# Forge Viewer local package

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I was wondering if there is any (approved) way of having an offline copy of the up to date Forge Viewer js package (v2.14 at the time I'm writing this).

All documentations I've seen about the viewer use the CDN (or rather viewingservice) version and emphasize on specifying a version tag (e.g. https://developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/viewers/viewer3D.js?v=v2.14).

In some case it comes handy to have the full package (js, css, locales, textures, dds, etc...) locally.

npm package view-and-data ships a 2.5 version inside a zip (but github repo no longer exists), forge-rcdb.nodejs github repo used to embed it, and some old forks who do are still online (with an outdated version obviously).

In the same vein, https://autodeskviewer.com/viewers-dev/ seems to list all files (so one could script and retrieve them) but again is outdated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no downloadable package for the Autodesk Viewer. The Viewer is composed of multiple files and the list may change in future (js, css, png, rendering config, ...) - One easy way to get it locally is to go to https://extract.autodesk.io/ which is embedding the viewer files in the extraction process. The Autodesk copyright still applies, but there is no issue to get a local copy to run your app.

Comment: In my understanding, the viewer files fetching mechanic https://extract.autodesk.io is based on a hardcoded list, and get files from the viewingservice without specifying a version.

Some files seem missing (searchworker.js, wgs.js, but I'm not sure if they are relevant). Can I assume this list is safe to use for 2.14.2?

Comment: I maintain the list from fetching that list from our source tree - and I take the latest default version from our server.

Comment: Good to know. Thank you for the clarification.